# User input validation before sanitizing?

Tags: php, validation, html-entities, sanitize

If I want to validate user input, is it necessary to sanitize it beforehand?

```
$age = $_POST['age'];
if ($age == 18) {
    echo 'is 18';
}
else
{
    echo 'Is not 18';
}
```

does this example leave me vulnerable to attack? Should I have sanitised age before the if/else block?

> $age = htmlentities($_POST['age'])

or

> $age = stripslashes($_POST['age'])

Comment: Always sanitize first.

Comment: @JayBlanchard could you explain why if I don't intend on outputting the input or adding it to a database? thanks

Comment: It is just a good habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no possibility of any attack here. The input string is not evaluated as code or otherwise attempted to be executed in any way. You're just comparing a string to another string/number, which is a safe operation.